# Cipher.init() required for each message?

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, encryption

Assume two clients are exchanging secure messages back and forth.

Must this block be run every time for each message, or can any step(s) be done just once at start:

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
output = cipher.doFinal(content);
```

I guess to lend some context- although I don't (yet) understand the internals completely, it is my understanding that for security purposes it's important to change the IV for each message. So I think the answer to this question will depend on whether that step happens under the hood at the doFinal() stage or init()....?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct: to be safe you need to use a new,random, IV for each message. This means you either need to recreate the cipher or randomly set the IV yourself for each subsequent message. The former is probably safer since if you change ciphers or modes, there maybe some other state you need to randomly set as well and reinitializing  the cipher should handle all of it.

If you don't do this, you end up with the same rather bad bug SSL had with IV [reuse](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1078/how-does-a-cipher-block-chaining-cbc-attack-work-against-ssl).

Cipher.doFinal does not reset the cipher to a random IV. In fact, its far worse than that, it appears to reset the internal state to the same IV you started with. As shown by this code.

```
    Cipher f = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
     byte[] keyBytes = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,
                0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };

            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    f.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] iv = f.getIV();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f.doFinal("hello".getBytes())));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f.getIV()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f.doFinal("hello".getBytes())));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f.getIV()));
    System.out.println( Arrays.equals(f.getIV(), iv)); // true
```

Comment: Thanks! On a related note you might know- is it enough to have just one SecureRandom initialization, and use nextBytes from then on?

Comment: @davidkomer free advice: yes, you can keep relying on SecureRandom

Comment: nextBytes is fine. Just make sure  when you create the RNG you let it   seed itself( i.e. your not providing some predictable seed to it when you start up)  so f = SecureRandom(), f.nextBytes() should be fine, but SecureRandom(somefixedvalue) or SecureRand(currentTime) would not work.

Comment: Thanks- and on a more directly related note ;) does the IV get passed natively by Cipher? i.e. do each of the clients need to prefix the new random iv for encoding, and strip the prefix for use on decoding? or is this handled under the hood by Cipher?

Comment: No, it doesn't get passed around by any cipher mode I have ever seen. Just pre-pend 4 bytes to your ciphertext since the IV is fixed length

Comment: Also, if you should probably use an authenticated encryption mode or place a message authentication code on (IV||encrypted message) if you really want to be secure.

Comment: Yep- adding/stripping was required, thanks! (IV is 16 bytes with AES). Will look into authentication...