# how to use DES encryption decryption in java with Cipher class

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, des

There are other similar questions on SO but none of them solve my problem.
So, I ask a new question.

I have text to encrypt (String) and 8-byte key to DES encrypt it (and 16-byte key for EDE triple DES encrypt it) as byte-array.

How do I use Java's inbuilt `Cipher` class to encrypt and then decrypt my text?

Even If anyone suggests any other third party code, jar etc. as far as it supports this specific use case, it is also accepted.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: "how do I use java's inbuilt Cipher class to encrypt (and then obvs decrypt) my text"

Comment: Oh, it looked like a normal sentence due to the wrong punctuation.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071489/cipher-init-required-for-each-message for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Some code I use:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

        public class CryptoPropio {


            /**
             * Master password.
             */
            private static char[] PASSWORD;

            /** The Constant SALT. */
            private static final byte[] SALT = { (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x10,
                    (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x12, };

            /** The error des. */
            private static String errorDes = "Error al des/encriptar";

            /** The Constant ALGORITMO. */
            private static final String ALGORITMO = "PBEWithMD5AndDES";

            /**
             * Instantiates a new crypto propio.
             * 
             * @param pass
             *            the pass
             */
            public CryptoPropio(String pass) {
                super();
                PASSWORD = pass.toCharArray();

            }


            public String encrypt(String property) {
                SecretKeyFactory keyFactory;
                String result = null;

                try {
                    keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITMO);

                    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD));
                    Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITMO);
                    pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT,
                            20));
                    result = base64Encode(
                                    pbeCipher.doFinal(property.getBytes("UTF-8")))
                                    .toString();
                } catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
                        | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException
                        | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException
                        | BadPaddingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return result;
            }

            /**
             * Base64 encode.
             * 
             * @param bytes
             *            the bytes
             * @return the string
             */
            private String base64Encode(byte[] bytes) {
                return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(bytes);
            }


            public String decrypt(String propert) {
                String property = propert;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory
                            .getInstance(ALGORITMO);
                    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD));
                    Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITMO);
                    pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT,
                            20));
                    result = new String(pbeCipher.doFinal(base64Decode(property)),
                            "UTF-8");
                } catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
                        | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException
                        | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException
                        | BadPaddingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }

            /**
             * Base64 decode.
             * 
             * @param property
             *            the property
             * @return the byte[]
             */
            private byte[] base64Decode(String property) {

                return DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(property);
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is this `ALGORITMO` doing? I mean, I don't get what it is for. We are encrypting the `PASSWORD` and using the 8-sized byte array to generate the key. But in my case, 8/16 sized byte array *is* my key.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecretKeyFactory

Comment: ALGORITMO is the Algorithm used by the Cipher, as @ThreeSidedCoin said there are a lot of possibilities, any of them with pros and cons...use the algorithm that fits in your code.

Comment: @DavidHerrero and threesidedcoin, this is fine as far as my use case is concerned. But my problem is, I have the key as 8-byte byte[]. So why would I generate a key.

Comment: @ThreeSidedCoin and davidherrero, if this line `SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD));` is generating a key, why does it use `PASSWORD`, which is the text to be encrypted?

Comment: the answer is incomplete: Constantes.MYENC

Comment: In this case, PASSWORD is the key will be used for encrypt/decrypt. An example of use would be:
`CryptoPropio instance = new CryptoPropio(yourPasswordAsString);
instance.encrypt("TextToEncrypt");`

Comment: I sincerely hope this translates to "my crypto" instead of "proper crypto".

Comment: If `PASSWORD` is being used as key, this, in no way now, solves my scenario.